# Can an 2013 MacBook Air run a monitor at 144hz?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, games, gpu

Apparently 2013 13" MacBook Air has Intel HD Graphics 5000.

Is it possible to run a monitor at 2560x1440 at 144hz?

Comment: Why would you want to run a monitor at 144Hz?

Comment: It's for gaming. I know the settings would need to be set for very low quality.

Comment: Don't be dragged in by gamer nonsense. You can't see over about 60FPS. Maybe 90FPS if you want to rock out a bit. 144Hz is completely useless.

Comment: but @WilliamTFroggard - why be happy with *only* 90 when you can have more? - [These go to 11...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc) (couldn't resist;)

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard - I'm not sure why you say I can't see over 60FPS. I have a 144hz monitor, and there is a huge difference.

Comment: What happens when you try to run it at 144Hz?